# Redmine: Installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, raspberry-pi, redmine

I want to install Redmine on my Raspberry Pi2. When I tried to run the command `sudo bundle install --without development test rmagic` I got this as output:

> Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed,
>   and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all
>   non-root users on this machine. The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will
>   be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler
>   is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32,
>   x64-mingw32, x86-mswin32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle,
>   run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32 x86-mswin32
>   java`. The dependency activerecord-jdbc-adapter (~> 1.3.2) will be
>   unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is
>   installing for ruby but the dependency is only for java. To add those
>   platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform java`. The
>   dependency activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (>= 0) will be unused by any
>   of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for
>   ruby but the dependency is only for java. To add those platforms to
>   the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform java`. Fetching gem
>   metadata from https://rubygems.org/.. Retrying dependency api due to
>   error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Network error while fetching
>   https://index.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionpack-xml_parser%2Cactiverecord-jdbc-adapter%2Cactiverecord-jdbcmysql-adapter%2Ccapybara%2Ccoderay%2Ci18n%2Cjquery-rails%2Cmime-types%2Cmimemagic%2Cminitest%2Cmocha%2Cmysql2%2Cnet-ldap%2Cnokogiri%2Cprotected_attributes%2Crack-openid%2Crails%2Crails-dom-testing%2Crails-html-sanitizer%2Crbpdf%2Crdoc%2Credcarpet%2Crequest_store%2Crmagick%2Croadie-rails%2Cruby-openid%2Cselenium-webdriver%2Csimplecov%2Ctzinfo-data%2Cyard..........
>   Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/... Fetching
>   dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.. Resolving
>   dependencies........................... Using erubis 2.7.0 Using
>   bundler 1.14.6 Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: no such name
>   (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-12.0.0.gem) An error occurred while
>   installing rake (12.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that
>   `gem install rake -v '12.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
>
> Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: no such name
>   (https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n-0.7.0.gem) An error occurred while
>   installing i18n (0.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that
>   `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.

And when I wanted to run `gem install rake -v '12.0.0'` or `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'` the command did not started and I got only `>` symbol on the start of the row, like when I want to edit something on mySQL through CLI.

What I missed? I didn't found this in the Documentation. I installed followed by [these steps](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Installation-procedure).

Comment: Does your Raspberry have access to the internet?

Comment: Yes and I cloned the Redmine directory from the official git repository

Comment: How did you install ruby on your pi? Compiled from scratch? RVM? Anything else?

Comment: @Jeremie I installed with the `apt-get` method

Comment: What do you get when you run `gem list`?

Comment: @Jeremie [Output](https://jsfiddle.net/tm2tyoL2) . The `gem list` was too long so I pasted it to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't had enough free space on my Rasperry. After cleaning some unnecesary documents it was install easy to install

Answer (score 0):

Getting a new line with `>` at the beginning after pressing Enter in the shell is usually a sign of unbalanced quoting. Are you sure you entered the `gem install` commands correctly?

Your errors when running `bundler` look like network problems. Most probably on your side, but rubygems.org has had connectivity problems a couple times in the past so it's not entirely impossible the problem was on their side or somewhere in between. Retry a couple hours later and it should simply work.